# Sending and Receiving data from Activity to another activity that extends fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am having trouble sending data from an Activity that is extending AppCompatActivity and receiving it in an Activity that is extending a fragment class. The problem is that i cannot extend AppCompatActivity in the receiving class as i am working with a java library that incorporates animated charts and the extension of that fragment class is needed so that the activity recognises some of the methods.... I have used debugger and it seems that the data is being added to the bundle succesfully, however, the bundle is returning null on the receiving end. (Code Below)

Sending Activity:

```
public class CreateLine extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Button dateButton, nextButton;
    TextView quantity, duration;
    Date date = new Date();
    String PackageType20 = "648 Shippers";
    String PackageType30 = "605 Shippers";
    int timeadded;
    private Spinner spinner, spinner2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_line);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.durationtextView);
        dateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.angry_btn);
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Confirm_button);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(com.almac.tracker.CreateLine.this,
                R.layout.spinner_layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LineTypes));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long l) {


                switch ((int) position2) {
                    case 0:
                        quantity.setText("");
                        ;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        timeadded = 10;
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        timeadded = 10;
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        timeadded = 10;
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Package Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(com.almac.tracker.CreateLine.this,
                R.layout.spinner_layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PackageTypes));
        myAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        spinner2.setAdapter(myAdapter2);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        quantity.setText("");
                        ;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        quantity.setText(PackageType20);
                        timeadded = 28;
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");


                        break;
                    case 2:
                        quantity.setText(PackageType30);
                        timeadded = 27;
                        duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dateButton.setText(date.toString());

                // Creates an instance of current DateTime which represents the
                // current date time.
                DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");
                String formattedtime = fmt.print(dateTime);
                dateButton.setText(formattedtime);

                // Plus some hours, minutes, and seconds to the original DateTime.
                DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");

                DateTime dateTime1 = dateTime.plusHours(timeadded);
                String endtimecalc = fmt2.print(dateTime1);
                TextView endtime = findViewById(endtimetextView);
                endtime.setText(endtimecalc);

                String spinnerSelection = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
                String spinnerSelection2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
                String q = quantity.getText().toString();
                String d = duration.getText().toString();

                //INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(
                        spinnerSelection,
                        spinnerSelection2,
                        q,
                        d,
                        formattedtime,
                        endtimecalc);

                if (isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(CreateLine.this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(CreateLine.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

                    StringBuffer buffer0 = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer buffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer buffer2 = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer buffer3 = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer buffer4 = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer buffer5 = new StringBuffer();
                    StringBuffer buffer6 = new StringBuffer();


                    if ( res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                            buffer0.setLength(0);
                            buffer1.setLength(0);
                            buffer2.setLength(0);
                            buffer3.setLength(0);
                            buffer4.setLength(0);
                            buffer5.setLength(0);
                            buffer6.setLength(0);

                            String getid = res.getString(0);
                            String getlt = res.getString(1);
                            String getpt = res.getString(2);
                            String getqty = res.getString(3);
                            String getdur = res.getString(4);
                            String getst = res.getString(5);
                            String getet = res.getString(6);

                            buffer0.append(getid);
                            buffer1.append(getlt);
                            buffer2.append(getpt);
                            buffer3.append(getqty);
                            buffer4.append(getdur);
                            buffer5.append(getst);
                            buffer6.append(getet);
                        } while (res.moveToNext());
                    }


                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                extras.putString("ID", buffer0.toString());
                extras.putString("LineType", buffer1.toString());
                extras.putString("PackageType", buffer2.toString());
                extras.putString("Quantity", buffer3.toString());
                extras.putString("Duration", buffer4.toString());
                extras.putString("Starttime",buffer5.toString());
                extras.putString("endtime", buffer6.toString());
                fragment.setArguments(extras);



                setContentView(R.layout.line_details);
                SamplerAdapter samplesAdapter = new SamplerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                ViewPager samplesPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.samplesPager);
                samplesPager.setAdapter(samplesAdapter);


            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Receiving Activity:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_details, container, false);

    Bundle extras = this.getArguments();
    if (extras != null) {

        String id = extras.getString("ID");
        String linetype = extras.getString("LineType");
        String packagetype = extras.getString("PackageType");
        String Quantity = extras.getString("Quantity");
        String Duration = extras.getString("Duration");
        String Starttime = extras.getString("Starttime");
        String endtime = extras.getString("endtime");

        TextView LT = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewLT);
        TextView PT = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewPT);
        TextView QTY = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewQTY);
        TextView DUR = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewDUR);
        TextView ST = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewST);
        TextView ET = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewET);

        LT.setText(linetype);
        PT.setText(packagetype);
        QTY.setText(Quantity);
        DUR.setText(Duration);
        ST.setText(Starttime);
        ET.setText(endtime);
    }

    return myInflatedView;
}
```

SAMPLERADAPTER CODE (with getitem method) :

```
public class SamplerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final int mCount = 10;
private Bundle extras;
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

public SamplerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle extras) {
    super(fm);
    this.extras = extras;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    fragment.setArguments(extras);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    super.finishUpdate(container);
}
```

}

Could anyone append my code so that it is receiving the data and displaying it to the text boxes that i have specified.

Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: show whole code for Sending Activity:

Comment: If one class extends fragment then it's not an Activity.

Comment: okay i will edit above

Comment: your Receiving Activity is Fragment?

Comment: i think so... "public class LineDetails extends SampleFragment {"     SampleFragment being the java class that i need to reference for the methods to be recognised for the animated charts to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the adapter constructer to receive Bundle
Pass the extras inside constructer like

```
SamplerAdapter samplesAdapter = new SamplerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), extras);
```

In SamplerAdapter class create one global variable for bundle

```
private Bundle extras;

public SamplerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle extras){
   super(fm);
   this.extras = extras;
}

// Now set these arguments in getItem method
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Create your fragment set arguments in that fragment
        Fragment fragment = new LineDetails();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: in the getItem method when I try to write fragment.setArguments it is not being recognised? is there somewhere I should be declaring this fragment?

Comment: I have added it above. Also in my LineDetails class what code do I need to change in order for your suggested answer to work?

Comment: create new instance for your receiving fragment instead of Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

Comment: so would it be Fragment fragment = new LineDetails? or how do I create that instance

Comment: okay the SamplerAdapter code now has no errors.. do I need to edit any of my LineDetails code for retrieving the data?

Answer (score 0):

first, you cannot create your fragment in sending activity. You must create it in a receiving activity that will instanciate the desired fragment.

Then, to communicate from sending activity to receiving activity, you have to send an intent.
Put your bundle inside this intent.
In receiving activity, you can call getIntent().getExtras() to obtain your bundle .
Instanciate your fragment and give bundle to it as you did.

Another thing, your while loop is "weird". If you already know that you will have one row result, don't create a loop and don't use Stringbuilder. If you can have several rows, don't reset lenght of StringBuilder at each loop because it will overwrite previous data at each new row.

Comment: I have tried to send the data using intent but i was told that this does not work within fragments and yes i am trying to display just the last line that was inserted into the database. At  the beginning it was displaying every row and i was told on this to use the setbufferlength method to show the last row.

Comment: I tried to use getIntent(), however, it is coming up in red.. what do you mean by instanciate my fragment? would you be able to show some code for receiving?

Answer (score 0):

From Activity you send data with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: While reading the bundle content in fragment always first receive the bundle into a Bundle object using getArguments method and check it against null. Otherwise, getString method will be applied on null and so the NPE when no bundle is passed. This will avoid the null pointer exceptions when the bundle is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can receive Intent in your activity and you need to pass the info to your working fragment. Given answers are OK if you need to start the fragment but if it's still working, `setArguments()` is not very useful. Another problem occurs if the passed information will cause to interact with your UI. In that case you cannot call something like `myfragment.passData()` because android will quickly tells that only the thread which created the view can interact with.